# Get position of first gallery image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, gallery

Some of my products have the first image set to position 0 and some has the first image set for position 1. Because of that, I need to run a check determining the id of the first gallery image. How can I do this?

I was thinking something like

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()[0]->getPosition();
```

But that doesnt seem to work..

Answer (score 1):

### Edited:

As `getMediaGalleryImages()` is  object of  ***Varien_Data_Collection*** class ,so you does not ***get data using generic php array index [0]***.

In this case you need to use  `getFirstItem()` function of  ***Varien_Data_Collection***.

```
$mediaGallery=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())
->getMediaGalleryImages()

echo $mediaGallery->getFirstItem();
```

**For getting first item position**  you need use ***position_default*** instead of ***position***

```
echo $mediaGallery->getFirstItem()->getPositionDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. Managed to get it to work, but for some reason I always get sortOrder 1 for the following, even though some of them have position 0:

`$_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();`
`$firstposition = $_gallery->getFirstItem()->getPosition();`

Comment: Would it be easier to get base image and call getposition on that?

Comment: `echo $mediaGallery->getFirstItem()->getPositionDefault();` use this code first item position

Comment: Still gives me 1 for all:
`$_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();
$firstposition = $_gallery->getFirstItem()->getPositionDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

To get an image from the gallery based on an attribute value, use **getItemByColumnValue** function. Also, to get the media gallery including excluded images, use **getMediaGallery('images')**

Example:

Always get the second image in your specific case

```
$images = $product->getMediaGallery('images');
$i = 0;
foreach ($images as $image)
{
if ($i == 1)
{
   $secondImage = $image;
   break;
}
$i++;
}
```

First answer:

To get the first image position:

```
$_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();

$_firstImagePosition = $_gallery->getFirstItem()->getPosition();
```

To get all the images position:

```
$_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();

foreach ($_gallery as $_image)
{
$_imagePosition = $_image->getPosition();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also clarify why `$_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImag‌​es(); $firstposition = $_gallery->getFirstItem()->getPosition();` always returns 1 even though a lot of my products have imges with position 0?

Comment: @Digital Pianism thanks .. i will  cross check..

Comment: Actually seem like there isnt any index in the log:
http://pastebin.com/015ThH3Z

Comment: @DigitalPianism ,you are right,Thanks for notice me the wrong ....Already give you upvote

Comment: This still returns 1 for all images, even though some should be 0:
`        $i_im = 0;
        foreach ($_gallery as $_image ):
        $i_im++;
        if($i_im == 1){
        $_imagePosition = $_image->getPosition();
        }`

Comment: Still doesnt work :-(
log and image for one with sorting 0:
http://pastebin.com/GgjRdQsR
http://i60.tinypic.com/2mmtgdc.png

Comment: Hang on!!! The "exclude" checkbox of the first image is ticked!! That is the issue. Ticking this checkbox means the image will not be included in the media gallery!

Comment: Of course!! Thanks. However - I need to to that in order to avoid getting the first image shown double in my lightbox.

Comment: Main problem - on my front page I have some featured products. When hovering over these, a second image is shown. This is always image no. 2 - so in products starting at 0 it is the third image and with products starting at 1 its the second. I would like it to always be the second image..

Comment: Oh well, it could have been easier then. Check my answer edit using the getItemByColumnValue function ;)

Comment: Thanks! But will that get the second image, or the image with position 2? If the first has position 0, I need the one with position 1. But if the first has position 1 I need the one with position 2. Thats why I wanted to check the first one :-)

Comment: Ok see my edit in your case ;)

Comment: The following always return true :-(

`$_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();

$imageOne = $_gallery->getItemByColumnValue('position', 0);

if (!$imageOne)`

Comment: See my edit to get the gallery images including excluded images ;)

Comment: Really happy for your help. Thanks! However, it still doesnt work. As soon as I add one of the the following, the site refuses to work `$_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGallery('images')->getItemByColumnValue('position', 0);`

`$_product->getMediaGallery('images')->getItemByColumnValue('position', 0);`

Comment: I originally thought it failed if the position didn't exist, but I tried adding the whole string in the if-clause instead and it still fails :-/

Comment: I can load the getMediaGallery('images') just fine, but as soon as I add the getItemByColumnValue('position', 0) the site just hangs.

Comment: See my edit for a different approach.